# duplicate symbols in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple google map into which I have placed markers at random locations. I have used map.fitBounds and bounds.extend APIs to automatically resize the map based on my canvas size. Sometimes , if I reduce the canvas size, the symbols duplicate in the background.

```
$(function(){
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var image = 'img/';
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var loc;

var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

loc = new google.maps.LatLng(52.696361078274485, -103.0078125);
bounds.extend(loc);
addMarker(loc, 'Event A', "active");

loc = new google.maps.LatLng(66.37275500247456, -146.25);
bounds.extend(loc);
addMarker(loc, 'Event B', "active");

loc = new google.maps.LatLng(62.75472592723178, 81.9140625);
bounds.extend(loc);
addMarker(loc, 'Event C', "active");

loc = new google.maps.LatLng(77.54209596075547, -49.5703125);
bounds.extend(loc);
addMarker(loc, 'Event D', "active");

loc = new google.maps.LatLng("1.3887035","1.1807378");
bounds.extend(loc);
addMarker(loc, 'Event E', "active");

map.fitBounds(bounds);
//map.panToBounds(bounds);    

function addMarker(location, name, active) {          
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        title: name,
     });
}

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G6PLr/5/

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: you're missing your code from the question that would help us identify any possible problem in your approach

Comment: @duncan I have specified the jsfiddle link now. If you notice the marker in Asia is duplicated. I tried setting minZoom as 1, but in that case the symbols get hidden. My requirement is, google map must render within any container of given height and width without being hidden and without duplication.

Comment: The symbols are only duplicated because that part of the map is: if you have two views of Asia, you would expect to see the Asian marker twice. This seems like expected behavior. Can you not, instead, set the min zoom level or max extents to prevent multiple country views.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes as you say I have tried with minZoom:1.But symbols get hidden if the width of canvas is reduced. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/G6PLr/13/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle. I finally managed to resolve the problem.

```
fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/G6PLr/119/
```

To sum up I did the following:

1. to avoid duplication of background setting minZoom as 1 worked out.
2. next determine the south-western most point (min lat and min long)
3. determine the north-eastern most point (max lat and max long)
4. fit bounds using these points

Voila, there it all falls into place. I am not sure why google doesn't do this automatically.